# Mysql delete first 4 characters with space

Tags: mysql

How remove row if first 4 characters contains one space is required or more spaces see the example

```
I try this 
DELETE FROM table
WHERE substring(field,1,4) REGEXP '^[a-z ]+$';

+-----------+
| field     |
+-----------+
| a    asdad|
| aa   asdad|
| aaa  asdad|
| asda asdad|
|  asd asdad|
|   da asdad|
|    a asdad|
+-----------+

+-----------+
| new values|
+-----------+
| asda asdad|
+-----------+
```

Comment: Your data doesn't fit the requirement, what exactly do you try to solve?

Comment: The only exception is why `asd  asdad` was also removed, since it has 2 spaces and not one

Comment: @AlonEitan It only has 1 space in the first 4 characters.

Comment: @shmosel Opps, but I was talking about the 4th row in `old values`  - The double space doesn't work in the comments

Comment: @AlonEitan So am I.

Comment: @shmosel Forgive me, it's late on my timezone, I should get some sleep because I was wrong twice :(

Comment: How can the first 4 characters contain at least 1 space and more than 3 letters? Did you mean "more spaces and less letters"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the result as what you need:

```
SELECT col FROM tab
WHERE substr(col,1,4) like '% %'
```

Then do:

```
DELETE FROM tab
WHERE substr(col,1,4) like '% %'
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you need to remove all the values where there is at least one space in first 4 characters (in the example, first value gets filtered out even if it has 2 spaces), you can use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` MySQL functions to filter out the values, e.g.:

```
SELECT value 
FROM test 
WHERE INSTR(SUBSTR(value, 1, 4), " ") = 0;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22412/2/0)**.

Comment: That'll filter out values with 2 spaces also.

Comment: No example had 2 spaces in the first 4 characters.

Comment: "if first 4 characters contains 3 letters and one space or more spaces"

Comment: Didn't notice that. Now I'm confused though. How can the first 4 characters contain at least one space and more than 3 letters?

Comment: That would be a counter question to OP I guess :P